# Built and nurtured good team and base for the project. Some one else taking over and plans to replace

Tags: team

**Context:**
I am a Lead Developer working for a US based client. Client operates on a client-vendor-employee model. My Employer is the vendor to the client. In our team there are other team members who are from different vendors.

**Situation:**
Last year, the client manager gave me the role of Team Lead. And I took that and worked hard to nurture subject matter experts, good team spirit, necessary environment and infrastructure. Went good for 1 year and got good results and accolades for myself and team.

Majority of the Employees are from another Vendor, who have an offshore in India. Their management proposed all the project work for a lesser price, the contract was signed off, and the project went to them. I have been given another role for another small project.

**Problem:**
Now based on trustworthy sources there is information the vendor is planning to replace all other vendors and take over all of the projects. And they are showcasing their resources, who are my ex-team members. Accordingly to my team members, the behaviour has also changed. Below are the few things I am quoting.

- There is a clear separation between their vendor resources while they are talking and behaving.
- They are showcasing all the knowledge and expertise as their own achievement and not even quoting any of my efforts behind that.
- And they have stopped showing respect and are starting to ignoring any of the requests and suggestions that I have given.

It hurts me and makes me feel very bad. I feel all the efforts that I have invested in the last year are wasted. How do I deal with these team members further?

Being that I am a consultant for a different Vendor to a common client, to whom should I address my concerns and get assistance in defending what appears to be an aggressive business move by this competing vendor?

What are constructive steps that I have to take right now and what constructive behavior and attitude to show to wards the situation?

Comment: I have no good answer, so I comment: This matter seems to be out of your league and is sad happening. I would qualify it to be aggressive takeover in a sense that no respect and cooperation is shown. Sadly it is a valid market strategy, which can work and is efficient, and ignores moral values, furthermore most often it is contraproductive in the long run. Hopefully you can contest with it, or challenge them! I'm clear that general the KPIs do not include good morals and authentic sources... so I wish best chances, and hope somebody has here a good idea!

Comment: What is your actual question?  Can it be summed up as you dont like how your ex team is being managed now and is there anything you can do?

Comment: Recognize that this is a situation that is out of your control.  You have been given a new assignment and what you should do is focus on executing that assignment to the best of your abilities.

Comment: Welcome to the real world. Your story happens everywhere. Either you eat me or I eat you. Nothing strange and worth complaining. If you don't like it, go somewhere else or start up your own company. Make enough money and then retire early to enjoy the rest of your life.

Comment: We can not decide what you should do.  We can try to help you solve a problem if you have a goal you would like to achive.  The edit I made appears to be the question you should probably ask that we can answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise your manager from your employer what the situation is.

Assuming your employer is also bidding on these projects this misinformation is putting your employer at a competitive disadvantage so it is part of your duty as an employee to move this information up the chain.  Highlighting your contributions for the client as part of these bids will at very least cast some doubt on claims the competition is making.

Do this as soon as possible as it is potentially very time sensitive.  Once the bids are awarded, it will take much more compelling evidence to sway the course of action.