# What kind of preventive measures that I took in order to other Vendors taking over my plans and replace me?

Tags: team

This is continuation to below [my earlier Question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78173/built-and-nurtured-good-team-and-base-for-the-project-some-one-else-taking-ove).

**Context:** I am a Lead Developer working for a US based client. Client operates on a client-vendor-employee model. My Employer is the vendor to the client. In our team there are other team members who are from different vendors.

Situation:I worked hard for an year and nurterd good team and prepare strong base for success of the project. My team members most of them belongs IT outsourcing Organization. After an year this Outsourcing Company shows competent teammember who are nurtured by me and take over the entire project and I lost my role and my plans in the project.

**My Intention**I have talked with my manager and my manager shows me another good opportunity, where as I have to start again from Zero. Based on the past experience, I would like to avoid the earlier debacle.

What kind of preventive measures that I can took from starting?

**Updates based on Comments**
*What Kind of Contract?*
 I am hired Employee for the Client. My Contract is getting extended as long as client have work for me.

*Where Does Client and Vendor Live?*
Both Live in USA in the same City.

*What Country laws are you legally subject in your work*
US Labor Laws

Comment: lacks Information, what Kind of contract do you have where do you live, where does your Client and vendor live. What Country laws are you legaly subject to in your work.

Comment: You may need to change your idea of "success". "I built a team that could complete the project without me." is a major win, far beyond "I got the project done but it will be a disaster if I leave the team.". Your manager seems to recognize that,  and want to use your team-building skills on another project.

Answer (score 4):

This is how life works, it's not enough to be good at a certain time and train others, you need to stay one step ahead and become better yourself.

Unless you own your own business you can't make the decisions which keep you on top of the heap, everything you do belongs to your employer and is done on their behalf. They will go with the cheaper option where they can that produces equivalent results.

So you upskill yourself, you innovate, you go the extra and make yourself more valuable to lose than to let go and replace. Once you get to the top, promotion is what you should be looking at if you don't want to tread water and watch others go past. One year and one project isn't much though, a few of these under your belt successfully is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have an incorrect image of what a leader is. A good leader does not hold on to his leadership but *gives it away*.

Your manager recognized that you helped get that team off the ground. Now he has a next job for you - as you name it *another good opportunity*. So what is the issue? It is your interpretation to name the previous 'job' a *debacle* - his interpretation seems to differ.
Likewise, if you were really a good leader, the people who you have worked with will remember that.